# The common major difference in thermal conducting properties between a random rock sample and metal?

Tags: temperature, metals

what are some common major differences in thermal conducting properties between a random rock sample(non-metal) and metal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can only be a single difference, not differences in thermal conductivity when comparing any two things as there is only one parameter to compare.

Very generally, metals are excellent thermal conductors and rocks are poor conductors.

[Here is a list of thermal conductivites](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_thermal_conductivities)